# Internationalization of java bean validation with ValidationMessages.properties

Tags: java, validation, internationalization, hibernate-validator

How do one internationalize java bean validation?

Before internationalization i have (something like) the following validation error message:

`email is not a valid email address (was some-nonexistant-user[at]invalid.email)`

And according to : https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkahi.html one can create a ValidationMessages.properties file to internationalize the text

For example if i add the contents (keeping it in english for demonstrative purposes, alltough this should be in another language)

`org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Email.message=is invalid email format`

Now this creates the following validation error:

`email is invalid email format (was some-nonexistant-user[at]invalid.email)`

So this seems to only give me control of a small portion of the text, but how do i customize for example the `was` part? And can have full control of the entire text? something like:

`{property} is invalid (data = {value})`

which would instead give me the output of

`email is invalid (data = some-nonexistant-user[at]invalid.email)`

Comment: I did this before, you will need to create a wrapped `MessageInterpolator`, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't do what you want through the localized properties files, you'll likely need to create your own MessageInterpolator.

See section 4.3.2 at http://beanvalidation.org/1.0/spec/#validationapi-message

Comment: So in other words, there is no way of customizing the messages further without resorting to your own MessageInterpolator?

Comment: Yeah, that's the way it seems based on my reading. Basically there's a default interpolator that only does so much for you. Anything more complex is up to you .. but maybe someone's put something open-source out there for you to use. I didn't check on that. Another thing you can do is just match the ContraintViolation objects with the failed value, and add something to the message. Post-process the message, in other words.